# Strange behavior with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to perform this type of rewrite

```
http://sitename/foo/var1/var2 -> http://sitename/foo/index.php?/var1/var2
```

This is my .htaccess file(placed in the directory foo):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

In my php script I am displaying the values of `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

If I request a URL like `http://sitename/foo/bar` the values as expected are `bar` and `/foo/bar` respectively.

This also works as expected for: `http://sitename/foo/admin` and `http://localhost/foo/bar`.

However when I try to access `http://localhost/foo/admin` (using localhost instead of sitename) the REQUEST_URI changes to `/admin/?admin` (this is how it displays in the address bar too, i.e `http://localhost/foo/admin/?admin`)

I searched for any .htaccess files that might be conflicting and also turned on mod_rewrite logging at level 6 but was unable to find any info.

I have no clue what might be causing it. It would be great if I could know what might be causing this, otherwise I might switch to nginx.

Comment: Why don't you change the rewrite to `index.php?path=$1` and read it from `$_GET['path']`, rather than relying on how the environment is set up.

Comment: I later found that the problem was with the cache of the browser. But I still followed your suggestion and replaced the destination part with path=$1. Now $GET always contains 'index.php'(as does $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] the parameters that I am passing are in variable $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY'] string. Am I missing something. The line that I modified is: 'RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [L]'

Comment: Edit: I moved the whole setup to a new VM and surprisingly everything works as expected. I think I'm just having one of those days.

Comment: we'll need some more infos on how your apache is configured, run apache2 -S to get list of virtualhosts (may need a ". /etc/apache2/envvars" before on debian), sitename and localhost may be served from different virtualhosts, and you'll need to check the difference between them

Comment: @regilero I just dumped the whole configuration and started fresh on a new server which is working exactly as I want without changing the .htaccess .

Comment: Make sure you don't have a folder named admin, since you wrote .htaccess to prio picking existing files first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for replies. This was some weird server configuration error, things seem to be fine on the new VM I installed. @Dan Grossman , thanks for your suggestion about using $_GET, some of my code is simpler than earlier.